# Improve SQL performance while searching products on website

Tags: performance, mariadb

I have online shop with more than 1000000 products. I've managed to improve performance in almost all areas, but while searching for product in search tab search query takes 15s.

How can I improve MariaDB performance related to search? Or is this CMS related?

Comment: using index (clustered), fix your query

Comment: You _must_ tell us the code used to do the search.  _Then_ we can make suggestions on how to speed it up.  Also, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, so we know _what_ you are searching.